# How do you display an image in a <video> player than is playing an audio file?

Tags: android, html, html5-video, html5-audio

Thanks to the eccentricities of Android 2.2, I am trying to play audio files in a `<video>` element. (Android 2.2 supports `<audio>`, but its player supports [no audio codecs](http://www.brianhadaway.com/html5-audio-support-on-android-devices/); its video player, however, has no such difficulty.)

They play fine, but when you play a video, it takes over the entire device with (in the case of an audio file) a blank screen. How can I put an image on the screen in place of the (nonexistent) video while the audio file is playing back? (I've tried setting the `poster` attribute of the `<video>` tag. It doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with default media player. If you need such a feature, I think you'll do it yourself…